# Can't generate flows from RAML in APIKit

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have the same problem mentioned here but don't see an answer. https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/25918/mule-flow-is-not-generated-using-apikitraml.html

Basically I have this simple RAML file and I'm trying to create a new APIKit project with it. I have successfully used this RAML before, but now when I try Anypoint Studio generates an empty config file. The poster on the Mule Forums said this is fixed in the 6.0 beta, but I can't use that version and feel like there must be a fix since this was working before. Any ideas?

```
%RAML 0.8
 title: WorldGreetings
 version: 1.0.0.0
 baseUri: http://localhost:8081/world

 /hello:
   get:
     description: Returns all care types.  Sorted by "rank" field in CRM.
     responses:
       200:
         body:
           text/plain:
             example: Hello World!
 /goodbye:
   get:
     description: Returns all amenities.  Sorted by name.
     responses:
       200:
         body:
           text/plain:
             example: Goodbye World!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that Anypoint had a path name that was too long. If I tried to reinstall I got a warning about an APIKit file path being too long and would not be copied. I reinstalled to C:\a and now everything's working fine.